# Set Click in a textbox with zk

Tags: java, forms, zk

I am using ZK Framework and i have a form, but the problem is that when the browser save the password i need do a click in the textbox of username and do a click in the textbox of password, and when the click is done the page submit my form well, but if i do not click in the textbox when i do click in the login button is like my textbox are empty.

Then i need do clicks because if i do not clicks in the textbox is like my textbox are empty,

How can i send a click in the textbox in zk or in my model in Java. Or how can i save the username and password saved by the browser in my textbox?

Who can help me.  Thanks

Comment: Please add your java und zul code. Without that it's hard to tell, what you're doing.

Comment: Did you ever get a work around for this situation? I am experiencing the exact same thing - the browser populates the username and password fields but the values don't seem to push through to ZK. Calling getText() or getValue() returns an empty string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After struggling for hours with this too and trying what felt like everything and anything I finally came up with a solution that works!

The main issue here is that the browser doesn't fire the onChange() event of the input fields when it populates the username and password.

ZK relies on this to update its own component's value. Furthermore, this also makes it impossible for us to know exactly when the browser has populated the values.

The work-around that I have is to add a timer to your page which fires repeatedly and forces ZK's updateChange() routine from the client-side.

Given this basic scenario:

```
<form>
    <textbox id="loginUsername"/>
    <textbox id="loginPassword" type="password"/>
    <button id="loginButton" type="submit"/>
</form>
```

This timer would do the trick:

```
<timer id="timer" delay="500" repeats="true" w:onTimer="zk.Widget.$('$loginUsername').updateChange_();zk.Widget.$('$loginPassword').updateChange_();" />
```

It's important to note that the w:onTimer property is a client-side property and requires the following declaration in your top most element:

```
xmlns:w="client"
```

Even though it seems a bit brute-force it has no negative effects on the user inputting his / her username and password if it was not populated by the browser and you could easily stop the timer once the user does something on the page.

Answer (score 0):

try to use native html tags along with the autocomplete attribute like this:

```
<zk xmlns:n="native">
    <n:form method="post" action="home.zul" autocomplete="on">
        username: <n:input type="text" />
        password: <n:input type="password" />
        <n:input type="submit" value="submit" />
    </n:form>
</zk>
```